# Table not found error while loading DataFrame into a Hive partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to insert data into Hive table like this:

```
val partfile = sc.textFile("partfile")
val partdata = partfile.map(p => p.split(","))
val partSchema = StructType(Array(StructField("id",IntegerType,true),StructField("name",StringType,true),StructField("salary",IntegerType,true),StructField("dept",StringType,true),StructField("location",StringType,true)))
val partRDD = partdata.map(p => Row(p(0).toInt,p(1),p(2).toInt,p(3),p(4)))
val partDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(partRDD, partSchema)
```

Packages I imported:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType,IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
```

This is how I tried to insert the dataframe into Hive partition:

```
partDF.write.mode(saveMode.Append).partitionBy("location").insertInto("parttab")
```

Im getting the below error even though I have the Hive Table:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: parttab;
```

Could anyone tell me what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write data to Hive warehouse, you need to initialize `hiveContext` instance.

Upon doing that, it will take confs from `Hive-Site.xml` (from classpath); and connects to underlying Hive warehouse.

`HiveContext` is an extension to `SQLContext` to support and connect to hive.

To do so, try this::

```
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
```

And perform your `append-query` onn this instance.

```
partDF.registerAsTempTable("temp")

hc.sql(".... <normal sql query to pick data from table `temp`; and insert in to Hive table > ....")
```

Please make sure that the table `parttab` is under db - `default`.

If the table in under another db, table name should be specified as : `<db-name>.parttab`

If you need to directly save the `dataframe` in to hive; use this:

```
df.saveAsTable("<db-name>.parttab")
```

Comment: could you tell where do you specify the dataframe here ?

Comment: I tried it like this:
scala> hc.sql("insert into parttab partition(location = 'India') select id,name,salary,dept,location from ptab"). 
getting error:
Caused by: ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1@25ac587b, org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home/cloudera/metastore_db.

Comment: As you're running in spark shell, you shouldn't instantiate a HiveContext with instance name `hc`, there's one created automatically called sqlContext.
(the name is misleading - if you compiled Spark with Hive, it will be a HiveContext). See similar discussion here: `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9776`.